# angular 4 - i want to create clone of the dom element

Tags: angular, typescript

i want to create a clone of the dom element for eg:-

```
<div>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p> 
<button (click)="copy()"></button>
</div>
```

here when i click on the button the whole div element should be cloned 
below it

if you click 10 times 10 clone should appear
also the orignal dom element should appear

i have tried with the ng-template ,elementrefrence ,render2 ,Viewchild

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use create an array and loop it through `ngFor`

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <p>{{item}}</p>
</div>


<button (click)="copy()"> copy</button>

 items: number[] = [1,2,3];
   copy() {
     this.items.push(this.items.length + 1)
  }
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pxkuru?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: i want to clone a dom element after the whole page is loaded

Answer (score 6):

Hope following code snippet help you:

```
import { Component,ViewChild,ViewContainerRef,ComponentFactoryResolver } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
      <div>
        <ng-template #clone>
          <p>lorem</p>
          <p></p>
          <p></p>
          <p></p>
          <p></p>
        </ng-template>
      </div>

      <button (click)="cloneTemplate()">Clone Template</button>

      <div #container></div>
    `
})
export class AppComponent{
    // What to clone
    @ViewChild('clone') template;

    // Where to insert the cloned content
    @ViewChild('container', {read:ViewContainerRef}) container;

    constructor(private resolver:ComponentFactoryResolver){}

    cloneTemplate(){
        this.container.createEmbeddedView(this.template);
    }
}
```

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rt5odg?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: yes something like this but the  element inside ng-template should also appear at first place

Comment: by default the whole div should appear at first then by clicking on the button
clone should appear

Comment: yes but that not what i want my div should appear first and then the clone of it should appear
in this demo what is happening is on every click the div and the clone both are appearing at the same time

Comment: What does `constructor(private resolver:ComponentFactoryResolver){}` do?

Answer (score 4):

I know it's too late probably but you can do it like this:

```
import {Component, ElementRef, TemplateRef, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  @ViewChild('viewContainer', {read: ViewContainerRef}) viewContainer: ViewContainerRef;
  @ViewChild('template') template: TemplateRef<any>;

  insertView() {
    const template = this.template.createEmbeddedView(null);
    this.viewContainer.insert(template);
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a8s6xg)